# Saving an image into sql server 2008 database issue?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, filestream

I have encountered the following error message while I trying to save an image from c# app. to SQL Server 2008 database.

**Note that loading is works fine, the problem is while saving.**

Please help??

> Failed to convert parameter value from picturebox to a Byte[]

The code to save an Image

```
 private void saveLogo()
            {

         SqlConnection   conn = new SqlConnection(dbcon.ReturnConnection());

            try
            {
         SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = conn.CreateCommand();
                sqlCommand1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO OrgLogo(ID,LogoName,Picture) values(@ID,@Name,@Picture)";

                conn.Open();
                if (sqlCommand1.Parameters.Count == 0)
                {                  
                   sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4);
                   sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@Name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                  sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@Picture", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image);
                }
          sqlCommand1.Parameters["@ID"].Value =Convert.ToInt32( editID.Text);
           sqlCommand1.Parameters["@Name"].Value = editName.Text;
           sqlCommand1.Parameters["@Picture"].Value = pictureBox1;

           sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();             

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();

            }
        }
```

The code to open the image file

```
protected void LoadLogoPic()
        {

            this.openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();

            string strFn = this.openFileDialog2.FileName;
                this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(strFn);
                this.openFileDialog2.Filter = "All Files|*.*|BMP Files|*.bmp|JPG Files|*.jpg"; 
                FileInfo fiImage = new FileInfo(strFn);
              m_lImageFileLength = fiImage.Length;
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFn, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                m_barrImg = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(this.m_lImageFileLength)];
                int iBytesRead = fs.Read(m_barrImg, 0, Convert.ToInt32(this.m_lImageFileLength));
                fs.Close();



        }
```

Comment: You are trying to store the *PictureBox control* instead of the image's data. If you pass the image's bytes (ie `m_barrImg`) as the parameter value, the statement will work at least for small pictures. For larger ones you'd have to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way;

```
Image img = picturebox1.Image();
byte[] arr;
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
arr=(byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ImagesTable (Image) VALUES('" + arr + "')";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The statement will end up as 'INSERT INTO ImagesTable (Image) VALUES('System.Byte[]')'. Using string concatenation is *never* a solution to SQL problems, it simply adds new ones as in this case. In fact, the OP's code would work if the actual byte array was passed instead of the control